Name of engineering civil construction device for flattening tarmac
I would like to know what is the name of the following engineering construction device for flattening tarmac (as in the picture).

Thank you for your feedback.

Compactor? Ramming machine?

British
surface (a road or other outdoor area) with tarmac or a similar material.
"they'll be wanting to tarmac the path" Google dict.

A "British surface with tarmac"? Weird, can we then say a "French surface" then? Maybe,  and because we're on a learners website, it should read British: A surface with… By the way, did the OP need the definition of tarmac? Doesn't look like it.

It is called is a plate compactor - this term is commonly used in both British and American English.
An informal term for the same device in British English is a wacker plate, or just a wacker. Note that the spelling of this is derived from a brand name Wacker Neuson, and is not a misspelling of 'whack', which coincidentally means to deliver a sharp blow.

Not for tarmac.
A wacker plate, also commonly referred to as a plate compactor or vibrating plate, is a piece of construction equipment with a vibrating metal base plate and an engine or motor on top of it. It is used for compacting various materials on the ground to create a solid surface and a level grade. Vibrating plate compactors are robust and heavy pieces of equipment, in order to ensure proper compaction.  https://www.nationaltoolhireshops.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-use-a-wacker-plate/#:~:text=A%20wacker%20plate%2C%20also%20commonly,surface%20and%20a%20level%20grade.

I thought Astralbee had it right, but that 'wacker' should be 'whacker', with no geographical exemptions.

Actually, this is a foot compactor, a plate compactor has a larger base and is lower to the ground and looks a bit like a lawnmower.

Wacker Neuson seem to have several types of products on its website, including  vibratory rammers and vibratory plates.  The sketch looks more like a rammer.

Here is a picture of a compactor

Such a device would be used for smaller areas of tarmac or asphalt, such as footpaths, as is common in the UK, and possibly elsewhere. In the UK, both asphalt and tarmac are widely used as road, pavement ('sidewalk') and driveway surfaces due to their durability, longevity, cost-effectiveness and the relative ease of installation.


The question in unclear. That machine works on small spaces, not a tarmac like at airport.

@Lambie - if I wanted to lay a tarmac driveway, I could hire a machine like the one in my picture (and the OP's) for around the equivalent of 100 US dollars a day.

@MichaelHarvey But you wouldn't use it on the topmost surface to flatten it evenly. It is for compacting the aggregate  below.

@Lambie The term "tarmac" can refer to the material, and does not necessarily have anything to do with an airport or have any particular size.

@nasch Sure, But the term seems> British
surface (a road or other outdoor area) with tarmac or a similar material.
"they'll be wanting to tarmac the path" in AmE we say pave.

Probably that machine is used by roadworkers for flattening potholes after they've been filled with that hot black sticky mix which I'd call either asphalt or tarmac. I ain't a technician, I'm not aware of any great difference in meaning…

@Mari-LouA Look at the Oxford Language google HIT: noun  trademark in UK
material used for surfacing roads or other outdoor areas, consisting of crushed rock mixed with tar.
"the tarmac path"
verb
1.
British
surface (a road or other outdoor area) with tarmac or a similar material.
"they'll be wanting to tarmac the path" Now, go look in in MW:

MW: : a tarmacadam road, apron, or runway
Tarmac
2 of 2
trademark
—used for a bituminous binder for roads

Pave Paradise, put up a parking lot!

Your fellow Brits  have this beautiful explanation of tarmac v. asphalt and how  a roller is used to compact it on a road https://www.hazellj.co.uk/tarmac-v-asphalt-which-should-i-use/https://www.hazellj.co.uk/tarmac-v-asphalt-which-should-i-use/ Hence my answer, since deleted, since for me a roller collocates with more than  the smaller compactor.  I doubt an AmE speaker would use tarmac as a verb. They paved the path and used tarmac.

@Lambie - When Tadloe walks the streets, the paviours cry, God bless you, sir—and lay their rammers by. - Tadloe (1727) was rather portly, I gather.

+1 The picture correctly shows what OP intended. I thought Tarmac only:meant a runway. But it's a brand name for asphalt. Cambridge dic
a brand name for a black material used for building roads, etc., that consists of tar mixed with small stones, or an area covered with this material
the Tarmac.
an area covered in Tarmac or similar material, especially the area in an airport where aircraft land and take off
tarmac
noun [ U ]
covered with a hard surface, esp. the areas of an airport where aircraft park, land, and take off:
The plane was damaged on landing when it slid off the tarmac.
